# Interactive selection with hex codes

Tags: string, characters, numbers

I want a function that can take a utf hexcode from the user, and use it to change the `glasses-separator` in `glasses-mode`.  When I use `completing-read` using a list of hexcodes things for well and the separator uses the corresponding symbol associated with the hex code.

I also want the ability for the user to pass whatever hexcode he wants to use (not just being restricted to the list).  I use `read-string` for the user input.  The problem is that if a user enters `\u21E8`, the result is that for that `CamelCase` gets modified to the string `Camel\u21E8Case` rather than using the symbol associated with `\u21E8` which is an arrow.

```
(defvar camelsens-actm nil)

(defun camelsens (hexcode)
  "Splits CamelCase phrases using separator."

(interactive
 (list
  (let* ( (optn '("list" "code"))
          (option (completing-read "Option: " optn nil t ""))
          (cseq '("\u27A4" "\u25BA" "\u2192" "disable")) )
    (pcase option
      ("list" (completing-read "Code: " cseq nil t "disable"))
      ("code" (read-string "Code: "))) )))

(pcase hexcode
  ("disable"
     (glasses-mode 0)
     (setq camelsens-actm nil))
  (_
     (unless camelsens-actm
       (glasses-mode 1)
       (setq camelsens-actm t))
     (setq glasses-separator hexcode)
     (glasses-set-overlay-properties))))
```

Comment: AFAICT, the main problem is that your function is not "clean", in the sense that sometimes the `code` variable is supposed to have a string value and sometimes it is supposed to be a single character (those are *different* types in Emacs Lisp and need conversion). But you seem wedded to writing functions in a particular style that makes it difficult (if not impossible) to know what it is supposed to be in any particular invocation, so you end up having to reason about *each case*. If you cannot describe what your function does in a sentence or two (with *no exceptions*), you should rethink it.

Comment: So instead of presenting a function that people have to figure out and then asking: "how do I fix this problem in it?", it is better to describe what you want to accomplish (in a couple of sentences, or in a prose paragraph if necessary, although it should be a *short* paragraph), and then study the responses carefully.

Comment: In particular, if the name of the function does not describe, more or less completely, what the function does, *that* is a problem.

Comment: Voting to close the question now. From the *plethora* of comments, to both the question and answers, it seems clear that the question isn't clear, and that there are multiple questions in it and it's evolving. This doesn't help readers. Please post *specific*, *single* questions, and don't try to turn this into a discussion site due to the possibility of helpful comments.

Comment: You post the same questions (and each is rarely a single question - more like an ongoing series of questions, often amounting to "please debug my code" - here, there, and everywhere. Friendly advice: it would help both *you* and others to try to focus your questions more. If you really want interactive *discussion* then try a site such as Reddit. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(defvar camelsens-actm nil)

(defun toggle-glasses-mode-and-or-set-separator ()
  "Ask the user some questions and use the answers to specify whether to disable `glasses-mode' or to make sure that it is enabled, change the separator and redisplay the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((option (completing-read "Option: " '("list" "code") nil t ""))
         (disable-or-separator-string
          (pcase option
            ("list" (completing-read "Code: "
                                     '("\u27A4" "\u25BA" "\u2192" "disable")
                                     nil t "disable"))
            ("code" (string (read-char-by-name "Code: "))))))
    (pcase disable-or-separator-string
      ("disable"
       (glasses-mode 0)
       (setq camelsens-actm nil))
      (_
       (unless camelsens-actm
         (glasses-mode 1)
         (setq camelsens-actm t))
       (setq glasses-separator disable-or-separator-string)
       (glasses-set-overlay-properties)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c z") #'toggle-glasses-mode-and-or-set-separator)
```

The name of the function tries to describe what the function does: the fact that it's a crazy name tells you something about the function. It's nevertheless  easier to understand, primarily because of the variable `disable-or-separator-string`: that too is a crazy name for a crazy variable, but at least it has the advantage of *always* being a string (and if it isn't then you know where to look for the error).

Comment: Quite crazy.   `completing-read` with `\u` does work but not with `read-char-by-name` which needs `#x`.  Am unsure whether there is an inconsistency with  `display-fill-column-indicator-character` which also takes unicode.

Comment: Now `glasses-mode` behaves as it should.

Comment: Yet, I do not see it too crazy to let a user decide which symbol to use for `glasses-separator`.  What improvements can be done for this to be simplified?  Changes to `glasses.el` perhaps?

Comment: That's not the crazy part: you can do that by customizing `glasses-separator` and you can use `C-x 8 RET` (bound to `insert-char`) there to insert arbitrary unicode characters. Why is that not good enough? The crazy part is wrapping simple things in complicated functions with complicated interfaces that need excruciating amounts of debugging to fix when they are broken (and because they are complicated, they are broken more often than not).

Comment: It would be an improvement if `insert-char` could also allow use of `\u2192` rather than only `#x2192`.

Answer (score 0):

You include lots of stuff in your question that seems extraneous, so it's not too clear what you're asking.

Is `string-to-char` what you're looking for?

```lisp
(string-to-char "\u2192") ; => character \u2192
```

Evaluating that with `C-x C-e` prints this. The #x2192 shows the number value in hex. Elisp characters are simply numbers.

8594 (#o20622, #x2192)

---

If that's really what you're asking then your question has *nothing* to do with *"interactive selection"* of anything, and certainly nothing to do with `glasses-mode`.

If so, consider getting rid of everything that's irrelevant and titling your question something like *"How do I convert a string that names a character to that character?"* And the answer to that simple question is to use function `string-to-char`.

If that isn't really what you're asking then I have no idea what is.

Comment: The problem is about the call to `(setq glasses-separator hexcode)`.  I am doing `(read-string "Code: ")`. When I input `\u2192`, the call to `(setq glasses-separator hexcode)` just uses the string `\u2192` as separator, rather than its unicode character.  But passing the code from `completing-read` does not introduce a problem.

Comment: So it *is* a string-to-char conversion problem, but it is mixed up in the convoluted interactive spec, which makes it difficult to figure out what is what in each particular case. You should step back and decide what the specification of your function should be: if you are not able to describe what your function is supposed to do in a couple of sentences, then rethink the spec first and *then* write the function to conform.

Comment: @NickD I have added more detail.  The interactive spec is important because it is the way that a user can supply the utf8 hexcode for `glasses-separator`.

Comment: I have put `("code" (string-to-char (read-string "Code: ")))` but the symbol still does not get inserted.

Comment: Use `read-char-by-name` instead: see the last paragraph in its description `C-h f read-char-by-name`.

Comment: Passing `\u2192` gives `(error "Invalid character") (read-char-by-name("hex: "))`.  Same if I input `2192`, `\U2192`, `\u+2192`.

Comment: I *did* ask you to read the last paragraph, did I not? Try `#x2192`.

Comment: Have tried that as well.  I also used completion using unicode names.  That also failed to set `glasses-separator`.

Comment: Well, there is another conversion problem: `glasses-separator` is supposed to be a string, not a character. So you are missing another conversion when you set it.